# Remove login (on my logins page) missing on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange.com

[image]

They're visible on stackoverflow

Comment: StackExchange.com merely displays an aggregate; it is not itself an account you can remove logins from, IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martijn noted in the comments, the profile on stackexchange.com is informational. If you need to add or remove login credentials, please do so from a Q&A site.

Comment: Why is this? I figured this out today, after noticing the "my logins" thing was present on Q&A sites too. Before that, I intentionally went to my network profile to remove a login because it seemed logical to me that I could change it there – and there the "my logins" link is hard to miss while it one of a list of links on SO for example.